# Searching with multiple values in django

Tags: python, django, search, filter

I want to create simple search in Django. I want to find all objects in which any word from keywords array is in meme.title or meme.author or meme.tags, and user.request is meme.user.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Meme(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete='CASCADE')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,
                         blank=True, max_length=1000)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    page_link = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=500)
    img_link = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

For example if I have keywords = ['funny', 'old', 'black_humor'] and current user is XYZ I want to find all memes that have that meme.user field is XYZ and title, author or tags contains any word from keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a Q Object.
By default if you use `filter` and chain severall argument it will use a AND logic.
For more complex query like chained AND, you need to use Q.
So your queryset should look like:

```
from django.db.models import Q
#get the current_user
current_user = request.user
keywords=  ['funny', 'old', 'black_humor']
qs = [Q(title__icontains=keyword)|Q(author__icontains=keyword)|Q(tags__icontains=keyword) for keyword in keywords]

query = qs.pop() #get the first element

for q in qs:
    query |= q
filtered_user_meme = Meme.objects.filter(query, user=current_user)
```

More info on Q obects : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Thanks, it's amazing.
But you have to change a few things.  
`qs = [Q(title_icontains=keyword)|Q(author_icontains=keyword)|Q(tags_icontains=keyword) for keyword in keywords]`  
Should be:  
`qs = [Q(title__icontains=keyword)|Q(author__icontains=keyword)|Q(tags__icontains=keyword) for keyword in keywords]`  
And  
`filtered_user_meme = Meme.objects.filter(user=current_user, query)`  
Should be:  
`filtered_user_meme = Meme.objects.filter(query, user=current_user)`  
Also delete ')' in the last line